# How to create distinct prototype variables for sub-prototypes?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, chain

Sorry for the confusing question title.

In short I want to be able to clone a new instance of E() into the prototype for B and C so that adding to B does not add to the array for C and vice versa, but all instances of these prototypes will have access to the same array if they are created from the same prototype.

This code hasn't been tested but it shows the method I'm using for extension, the actual code is very large. I'm able to achieve this in constructors but there's overhead for initialising each array on instance creation, I'd much rather have a common object per prototype and ideally that object would inherit it's properties from the next step up the chain( A in this example )

```
function ObjectA() {
    Object.create(this.sharedVariable);
}

ObjectA.prototype = {
    sharedVariable: new E(); //returns []
}

function ObjectB() {
   ObjectA.call(this);
}

ObjectB.prototype = Object.create(ObjectA.prototype );
ObjectB.prototype.sharedVariable.push("B");

function ObjectC() {
   ObjectA.call(this);
}

ObjectC.prototype = Object.create(ObjectC.prototype );
ObjectC.prototype.sharedVariable.push("C");

var B = new ObjectB();
var C = new ObjectC();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question properly, properties on prototypes are not shared for writing purposes. Consider the following:

```
function A() { }
A.prototype = { v: 1 };
function B() { }
B.prototype = new A();
b = new B();
b.v = 99
delete b.v
b.v // 1
```

In other words, even through `b` has the property `v` in its prototype chain, through `A`, when we assign `b.v` the assignment is to the local copy of `b`. When we delete the instance property, references to it revert to referring to the property in the prototype chain.

If you want to share a variable among instances, that is what is known in some schemas as a static variable, and it would live on A or B, rather than their instances. Of course, it could not longer be referred to as `this.a`, but would have to be `this.constructor.a`.

However, this does not easily solve the problem of having a "shared" (static) variable on A which is then also shared by its subclass B, so that an instance b of B can say this.constructor.v = 99 and have that value accessible to this.constructor.v on an instance a of A. More machinery would be required to accomplish this.

One general (?) solution would be to write getters and setters, along the following lines:

```
function inherit_static_prop(parent, child, prop) {
  Object.defineProperty(child, prop, {
    get: function() { return parent[prop]; },
    set: function(v) { parent[prop] = v; }
  });
}
```

Now, you can do

```
function A () { }
A.v = 1;
function B () { }
inherit_static_prop(A, B, 'v');
b = new B();
b.constructor.v = 2;
a.constructor.v // 2
```

Have fun.

#### OP comment

> Thanks this is a very comprehensive answer but what I'm looking for is
>   a way to decouple v from A when defining the prototype of B so that
>   initially b.v = 2, a.v = 2 but if I do b.prototype.setV(3) then b.v =
>   3, a.v = 2.

If I understand your question correctly, I think that will be the normal behavior:

```
function A() { }
A.prototype = { v: 1 };
function B() { }
B.prototype = new A();
b = new B();
b.v // 1
B.prototype.v = 3;
b.v = 3
```

To put it another way, you don't need to "decouple v from A when defining the prototype of B". It will automatically decoupled (shadowed) when and if you add a property of the same name to the prototype of B.

Comment: Thanks this is a very comprehensive answer but what I'm looking for is a way to decouple v from A when defining the prototype of B so that initially b.v = 2, a.v = 2 but if I do b.prototype.setV(3) then b.v = 3, a.v = 2

Comment: You're right, it's slightly different from how I was coming at it but it's a working solution and brought me to where I could also fix my own code in 2 lines. Thank you for all your help!